# Sqoop import having SQL query with where clause and parallel processing

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, sqoop

I have a table as below in mysql :

Order_Details :

```
+---------+------------+-------------------+--------------+                                                                                                                                                        
| orderid | order_date | order_customer_id | order_status |                                                                                                                                                        
+---------+------------+-------------------+--------------+                                                                                                                                                        
| A001    | 10/30/2018 | C003              | Completed    |                                                                                                                                                        
| A002    | 10/30/2018 | C005              | Completed    |                                                                                                                                                        
| A451    | 11/02/2018 | C376              | Pending      |                                                                                                                                                        
| P9209   | 10/30/2018 | C234              | Completed    |                                                                                                                                                        
| P92099  | 10/30/2018 | C244              | Pending      |                                                                                                                                                        
| P9210   | 10/30/2018 | C035              | Completed    |                                                                                                                                                        
| P92398  | 10/30/2018 | C346              | Pending      |                                                                                                                                                        
| P9302   | 10/30/2018 | C034              | Completed    |                                                                                                                                                        
+---------+------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

and the description as below :

```
mysql> desc Order_Details_Sankha;                                                                                                                                                                                  
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+                                                                                                                                                 
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |                                                                                                                                                 
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+                                                                                                                                                 
| orderid           | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI |         |       |                                                                                                                                                 
| order_date        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |                                                                                                                                                 
| order_customer_id | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |                                                                                                                                                 
| order_status      | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |                                                                                                                                                 
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I am using the below **sqoop import with parallel processing** :

```
sqoop import 
--connect jdbc:mysql://ip-10-0-1-10.ec2.internal/06july2018_new 
--username labuser 
--password abc123
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
--query "select * from Order_Details where order_date = '10/30/2018'  AND \$CONDITIONS" 
--target-dir /user/sankha087_gmail_com/outputs/EMP_Sankha_1112201888 
--split-by ","   
--m 3
```

and I am getting the below **error message**

```
18/12/15 17:15:14 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:sankha087_gmail_com (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You hav
e an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), MAX(,) FROM (select * from Order_Details_Sankha where order_date = '10/30/201' a
t line 1                                                                                                                                                                                                           
18/12/15 17:15:14 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), MAX(,) FROM (select * from Order_Details_Sankha where order_date = '10/30/201' at line 1                                                            
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.getSplits(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:207)                                                                                                       
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:305)                                                                                                                          
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:322)                                                                                                                             
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:200)                                                                                                                       
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1307)
```

**Please advise what needs to be changed in my import statement .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop parallel execution doesn't happen with vertical split, it happens with horizontal split.

**--split-by** should be a **column name**. column should be one which is evenly distributed.

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1765770

**Read: 7.2.4. Controlling Parallelism**

Comment: if You are using number of mapper in query than you not need to use --split-by clause

Comment: Thanks Gaurang ,it worked :) . I gave the Primary key column in --split-by .But tell me one thing under what scenario , I can use : --split-by ","

Comment: Thanks Mahesh for your response ,I tried giving only mapper number , then again it specifically asked for --split-By

Comment: That is not correct. If you are using more than one mapper you must need to specify `--split-by`,  as there is no way for sqoop to understand based on what tables nees to be divided for multiple mappers. It's not needed only if you use single mapper `-m1`

Comment: Hi Gaurang ,you are absolutely correct and with your solution I was able to execute it successfully.But apart from that I executed the below import where I specified the --split-by "," for mapper 1 and it worked .

Comment: sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://ip-10-0-1-10.ec2.internal/06july2018_new --username labuser --password simplilearn --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --table Order_Details_S
ankha --target-dir /user/sankha087_gmail_com/outputs/EMP_Sankha_18122018 --split-by ","   --m 1 --outdir /user/sankha087_gmail_com/outputs/spark_programs/fetchSelectiveDataSqoopImport

Comment: That's because when you pass `-m 1` then `--split-by` is ignored. So doesn't matter what you pass as value. Even the wrong one like `, `